# onCatchError does not come if instantiated via HTML (in combination with bind toValue)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm a bit confused about how AngularDart / DI instantiates new objects.

If I instantiate 'appcontroller' via HTML it never gets the catchError (it fails in the console with 'Uncaught Error...'). The odd thing is - this happens ONLY if I `bind(Proxy, toValue: new Proxy());` if I `bind(Proxy);` it works!

Another way to make it work is to make the completer in Proxy static.
Then `bind(SyncProxy,toValue: new SyncProxy());` is no problem and catchError comes.

If I run Controller, Proxy and Module in a unit-test it works too...

```dart
@angular.Controller(selector: '[appcontroller]', publishAs: "ctrl")
class Controller {
    final Logger _logger = new Logger("integration.test.Angular.Controller");

    final Proxy _proxy;
    bool _loadedWithError = false;

    Controller(this._proxy) {
        _proxy.load().catchError((final String error) {
            _logger.severe("Error X: $error");
            _loadedWithError = true;
        });
    }
}

@angular.Injectable()
class Proxy {
    final Completer<bool> _completer = new Completer<bool>();

    Future<bool> load() {
        //_completer.completeError("Error");
        new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1),() {
            _completer.completeError("Error");
        });
        return _completer.future;
    }
} 

class SampleModule extends angular.Module {
    SampleModule() {
        bind(Controller);
        // works for UNIT-Test but fails with HTML instantiation 
        bind(Proxy, toValue: new Proxy());
    }
}

main() {
    applicationFactory().addModule(new SampleModule()).run();
}
```

HTML-Code:

```
<body appcontroller>
...
```

**[ Update ]**
According to Günters answer below and my own tests the approach `bind(Proxy,toValue: new Proxy());` to create a Singleton is useless and counter-productive.

The normal `bind` is enough and **avoids the Zone-Problem**!

Comment: The difference is that with `toValue:` the instance will be created when `new SampleModule()` is executed and with `bind(Proxy)` the instance will be created when the `Controller` instance is requested from the injector by Angular. I guess this has to do with zones. It seems DI runs in another zone. In the 2nd case both instances are created in the same zone (by DI) in the first case the proxy is created in the default zone and the Controller in the zone DI works. Why do you need the `new Proxy()` anyway? If you need custom instantiation you could use `toFactory`.

Comment: Uhhh - as always thanks for your answer. I thought it must have something todo with a different scope, instance... whatever. I was not aware of Zones. the "new Proxy()" makes a singleton. In the real app the Proxy is a SyncProxy and this SyncProxy must have just one instance for the whole app.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works but it was explained several times that DI always only creates one instance. If you register it again on child injectors it will create another instance there but beside that, if you register it only in your AppModule there should always be only one instance in the whole application no matter how you register it.

Comment: Ohhh man... until now I thought it works the same way as Guice. After quit a few unit-tests I found out that in Dart it's much harder to create multiple instances than it is in Java. As you already said - in Dart, if you specify nothing special, DI creates only one instance per class. Actually you need two modules, two bind statements with either toValue or toImplementation to create a second instance! Its more or less the complete opposite then what I expected :-O Gist: http://goo.gl/tlH0gR

Comment: I had the same experience a few months ago ;-)